# Need to print to JTextArea continuously like a stream instead of one big lump

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am calling a recursive method that keeps on printing a string each time. The method has textArea.append(String) and system.out.print(string). The system.outs print like they should (like a stream of Strings). But the JTextArea only prints in one lump

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Also note that, `JTextArea` may need a chance to repaint itself. Read about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: Append is thread safe

Comment: Most likely, you are appending your strings continuously from the EDT (Event Dispatching Thread). Instead move that into a new Thread (either with `Executors`, `SwingWorker`, `java.util.Timer` or `javax.swing.Timer`). This will have a more "immediate" behaviour